# Sending a char array using RF24Network on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to use the [RF24Network](https://github.com/maniacbug/RF24Network) library to create a sensor network in which the root node connects to an MQTT broker using the [PubSubCient](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) library.

I have done a basic test which relays the MQTT topic and message payload from MQTT to one other node in the network, it does this by using `sprintf` to create a delimited string of the current `millis()` time on the root node, the topic and message which is stored in a car array of size 200 (as the size of the RF payload must be predefined), I can see from serial output that this is being done correctly.

However from the serial output of the receiving node I find that only the first 24 characters of the string are being received and I am out of ideas as to why this is the case.

Code for sending node:

```
void ByteToChar(byte* bytes, char* chars, unsigned int count){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         chars[i] = (char)bytes[i];
    chars[count] = '\0';
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* message, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.println("Sending...");

  char buf[length + 1];
  ByteToChar(message, buf, length);

  char payload[200];
  sprintf(payload, "%lu:%s:%s", millis(), topic, buf);

  Serial.println(payload);
  Serial.println(sizeof(payload));

  RF24NetworkHeader header(other_node);
  bool ok = network.write(header, payload, sizeof(payload));
  if (ok)
    Serial.println("ok.");
  else
    Serial.println("failed.");

  free(payload);
}
```

And receiving node:

```
while ( network.available() )
  {
    RF24NetworkHeader header;
    char payload[200];
    memset(payload, 0, 200);
    network.read(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));

    Serial.println(payload);
    Serial.println(sizeof(payload));
    free(payload);
  }
```

It's not impossible that I have just overlooked something very simple.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: This would probably be helpful, this is the data I am sending from the root node:
`4203:in_3:hello world again`

and this is what I get:
`4203:in_3:hello world ag`

Comment: And there's no embedded zeroes in the `message` data?

Comment: Without inserting the ```'\0'``` I was just getting garbage after the valid message, so I assumed there was no terminator on the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the source of size_t RF24Network::read

```
bufsize = min(maxlen,frame_size-sizeof(RF24NetworkHeader));
```

That are at most 24 bytes.

Comment: Damn, I had just started looking at the source, but yes, this is the problem.

Comment: I have tried payloads larger than 24 bytes, it works. Somehow, the lib supports a FRAGMENTATION feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried payloads larger than 24 bytes, it works. Somehow, the lib supports a FRAGMENTATION feature. 72-byte payload works on UNO, but not bigger.

https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24Network/AdvancedConfig.html